# Positive and Negative labeled data points Support Vector Machine

Tags: artificial-intelligence, svm

I was learning about SVM on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivPoCcYfFAw) and there is this example. Suppose we are given the following positively labelled data points,

```
{(3 1), (3 -1), (6 1), (6 -1)}
```

and the following negatively labelled data points,

```
{(1 0), (0 1), (0 -1), (-1 0)}
```

My question is how do you differentiate positive and negative labelled data points? Is it because there is 0?

And there is this problem on my book that said:

> Use values +1 and -1 (instead of 1 and 0) for the target output, so that the four input points and the corresponding target outputs look like ([0, 0], -1); ([1, 0], -1); ([0, 1], - 1); and ([1, 1], 1]

How can I determine what is positive and negative data points?

Thank you.

Comment: Roughly speaking, you label your point in two sets based on a choice of and hyperplane which separates them. In your case, you are on a plane, so the hyperplane is a line. The points are labeled by the group they are in considering a line which separates them in two groups.

Comment: Here's a link which explains in details how to choose hyperplanes https://www.svm-tutorial.com/2015/06/svm-understanding-math-part-3/